# Attempted Left Join in Query Syntax and Lambda results in "The method or operation is not implemented."

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I've attempted to write this query two different ways, and no matter how I write it, I can't get the join to pan out. It just keeps tossing `"The method or operation is not implemented."` at me. What I'm trying to do is, in SQL, simple: Obtain a list of items from table A (below - Customer) where there is no corresponding listing in table B (below - SalesReps).

Attempted Lamda:

```
var customers =
    _sms.CurrentSession.Query<customer>()
        .GroupJoin(_sms.CurrentSession.Query<salesReps>(), 
                    c => c.Id, 
                    sr => sr.CustomerId,
                    (x, y) => new {c = x, sr = y})
        .SelectMany(xy => xy.sr.DefaultIfEmpty(), 
                    (x, y) => new {c = x.c, sr = y})
        .Where(data => data.sr.SalesRepId == null)
        .Select(data => new CustomerDTO
            {
                Id = data.c.Id,
                FullName = data.c.FirstName + " " + data.c.LastName,
                FirstName = data.c.FirstName,
                LastName = data.c.LastName
            });

var custList = customers .ToList();
```

Attempted Query Syntax:

```
var customers = from c in _sms.CurrentSession.Query<customer>()
    join sr in _sms.CurrentSession.Query<salesReps>() 
        on c.Id equals sr.CustomerId 
            into joinedData
    from jd in joinedData.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where c.IsEmployee == false 
            && c.CustomerOptions.Company.Id == companyGuid
            && jd.SalesRepId == null
    select
        new CustomerDTO
        {
            Id = c.Id,
            FullName = c.FirstName + " " + c.LastName,
            FirstName = c.FirstName,
            LastName = c.LastName
        };

var custList = customers .ToList();
```

I get the impression that the issue is on the check for null sales reps, but I'm not sure.

Comment: can't you just check if the `SalesRep` property (object) is null?  If it is null, accessing `data.sr.SalesRepId == null` will fail, because `data.sr` is null and you can't access a property of a null object

Comment: I commented out the Where clause entirely, and the same error is still popping up... Perhaps attempting to shove everything into the DTO is where the failure is?

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of `_sms.CurrentSession.Query<customer>().Where( c => c.SalesRep == null)`.  Do you have `SalesRep` mapped on `Customer`?  That's what we'd do with an ORM like NHibernate.

Comment: The problem is that Customer is a gigantic object already, and SalesRep is entirely separate - it's a cross reference table.